# SharePoint 2013 - Tasks Assignment multiple users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, tasks

We control permissions to sites and libraries centrally and are building a process for users to request access changes.  We have a list setup on our site collection which has every list and library name in it which we update - each list and library has an owner and deputy - using the people picker.

The permission change request process list has a lookup back to this list which the user selects the library / list they want access too.

What we want to do is when a request for permissions is received as a new item for the workflow to assign a task to be completed by the owner **or** deputy to approve/decline the permissions change - the results of their decision to then be passed to the permission change request process into a field called status.

We have tried 2010 and 2013 workflows - 2013 works grand but if the owner approves it then the deputy when they try get a rubbish error message about the task being deleted. We haven't tried to pass the results back to the list.

We are running non enterprise version of SP2013 without InfoPath.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar project. I used a 2013 workflow to accomplish this. I used a task process to assign it to multiple users.

The process starts by checking current permissions against desired permissions. If they do not match it assigns a task process to the approves which looks up in another list. The workflow captures the approval status and use that to assign task or no task to the IT team.

[image]

The part you are most interested in would be after the 1st else.

It takes the approval status and passes it through, so it knows where the change has been approved. If it is approved it set's a variable saying it has been approved and attaches it to an email later in the workflow.

Task proccess can bee seen below. 
[image]